# Laravel raw select query takes 15 times longer when selecting VARBINARY(MAX) column

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, laravel, laravel-10

I noticed a weird behavior with my code.
I have a table that stores users' images in a `VARBINARY(MAX)` format (Not the best, I know, needs to be changed)

Now, I am trying to select the top 5000 users images.

When I type the following query in MS SQL, it finishes in 7 seconds:

```
select top(5000) user_id, user_photo from user_photos
```

When I do the same query with Laravel's raw query, it takes 110+ seconds in average:

```
$photos = DB::select("select top(5000) user_id, user_photo from user_photos");
```

Now, if I remove the `user_photo` from the select, it takes less than 0.3 of a second:

```
$photos = DB::select("select top(5000) user_id from user_photos");
```

So it has to do something with the `VARBINARY(MAX)` column that holds really long strings which doesn't play well with PHP or Laravel

But why?

Comment: Most likely it's data transfer times. If you are using a command like client the results are streamed inline rather than transferred from the database to whetever requests it

Comment: Or very possibly it's an indexing issue. Please show the table and index definitions, and please share the query plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

Comment: So, if you're selecting 5,000 images averaging 1 MiB each that's 5 GiB of image data it needs to download with the rest of your result set. How long do you think it should take?

Answer (score 3):

SSMS does not store in memory or display all data in blob columns by default, so while it's fetching all the data over the network it's not loading it all into memory or rendering it.  And the data fetching code path in SSMS is pretty well optimized.  No idea about Laravel is doing.

In your application you should avoid retrieving 5000 photos from the database.  Instead retrieve them one-by-one as actually needed.

Comment: thank you, in reality I don't retrieve all 5000 photos, but just wanted to check something specific before. What do you mean does not retrieve all the data in blob columns by default? Because I do see all of the strings in the Results pane. But maybe it doesn't really load all and just a few for the pane and shows more as I scroll down?